# Slicing different areas of two images in one go

Tags: numpy

Slicing different areas of two images in one go

I have two images of [2, height, width, channel] dimension and same size. I want to slice two images by a same size kernel (say 5 x 5) at different locations in one go. For example, for image one, the slicing area is [125px,125px] to [130px,130px]; for the second image, the slicing is [140px,140px] to [145px, 145px].

I used the following code
    imgs[:, yst:yend, xst:xend]
in which yst is the two-entry array of starting coordinates (i.e. [125, 140]) for two images respectively. yend is for the ending coordinates similarly. So do xst and xend for width axis coordinates.

Instead of getting two slicing areas, the code resulted in four areas. That is, the two slices had been applied to each image.

What I expect is that the first slice is applied to the first image and the second slice is applied to the second image respectively. I have tried various dimensional combinations and none of them worked as I desired so far. I ended up looping them one by one at the moment. But my gut feeling tells me it could be done in one go. Could anyone lend a hand on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show what the outputs look like? From your current description, it looks like you are applying the same slices across both images.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options to achieve what you want.

1. move to fancy indexing
2. use stride tricks

The latter is faster but a bit dangerous (a typo in the dimension setup magic can hard crash your script):

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
from scipy.misc import face
from timeit import timeit

def fancy_idx():
    ino, y, x = np.ogrid[:nim,:yw,:xw]
    ywo, xwo = ywoff.reshape(-1,1,1), xwoff.reshape(-1,1,1)
    return im[ino, ywo+y, xwo+x]

def stride_trx():
    nim, y, x = im.shape
    st = im.strides
    wins = as_strided(im, (nim, y-yw+1, x-xw+1, yw, xw), (*st, *st[1:]))
    return wins[np.arange(nim), ywoff, xwoff]

# set up example
# use the scipy example image
# use the color channels (RGB) as individual images
im = np.ascontiguousarray(np.moveaxis(face(), 2, 0))
nim = len(im)
# set the window height and width
yw, xw = 150, 200
# set the top left corners for window in each image
ywoff, xwoff = np.array([[510,530,520],[700,720,750]])

# test
assert (fancy_idx()==stride_trx()).all()

print(timeit(fancy_idx, number=1000))
print(timeit(stride_trx, number=1000))
```

Sample run:

```
0.4873827249975875    # fancy indexing
0.028213004930876195  # stride tricks
```

Some explanation:

1. fancy indexing: this method addresses each pixel individually, this is flexible and safe but slow
2. stride tricks: this method is faster because only the top left corner of each window is addressed fancy, the windows themselves are created by slicing

   how does it work? we essentially create a 5D array by duplicating (in admin, not in data) the y and x axes. That way we can use the first copy of y and x to pick the offsets and the second copy of y and x to slice

Comment: Thank you Paul. stride approach looks charming. I will figure it out the tensorflow equivalence.